# In-App Purchase is successful, but methods are not called

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm testing a *promoted* In-App Purchase, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_promoted_in-app_purchases).

Here's how it works:

1. I construct the system URL.
2. I send the system URL link to my device.
3. I tap the link.
4. My app is automatically opened, and the In App Purchase payment sheet is presented.
5. I tap the "Purchase" button (or whatever it's called), and enter my password to complete the transaction.
6. The transaction appears to be successful and an alert appears that says, "You're all set. Your purchase was successful".

The problem is, some code that should run depending on the state of the transaction seems not to. I'm not sure how that's possible, but there you go.

So, the `deferredTransactionHandler`, `handlePurchase`, `handleFailedPurchase`, and `handleRestoredPurchase` methods appear not to be invoked.

```
class StoreObserver: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate { 
    var productRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    var isAuthorizedForPayments: Bool {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    }
    var products = [SKProduct]()


    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
        //The user has initiated a promoted In-App Purchase directly from the app's product page.

        //Show the UI:
        SceneDelegate.mainData.showAppStorePromotionUI = true
        
        //"Return true to continue the transaction in your app. Return false to defer or cancel the transaction."
        return true
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
                case .purchasing: break
                case .deferred: deferredTransactionHandler(transaction)
                case .purchased: handlePurchase(transaction)
                case .failed: handleFailedPurchase(transaction)
                case .restored: handleRestoredPurchase(transaction)
                @unknown default: fatalError("unknownPaymentTransaction")
             }
          }
    }
}
```

How do I know these methods aren't being called? 1) Inside these methods, I update the UI to reflect that the transaction has completed (the UI is never updated, though), and 2) Inside these methods I try to present an alert (but the alert is never presented). Here's how I'm doing that:

```
func handlePurchase(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    //Update the UI
    SceneDelegate.mainData.showAppStorePromotionUI = false

    //Present an alert so you know this function ran
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "handlePurchase()", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
            
    }))
    let topViewController = UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.rootViewController
        
    topViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //Complete the transaction  
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

**Why does it seem that these functions are not being called? What am I missing?**

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you add your payment queue transaction observer?  You should do so in `didFinishLaunching`

Comment: Yes, I do add the observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and then I remove it in `applicationWillTerminate`.

Comment: You don't need to remove it, but that doesn't matter.  Do your payment queue observer methods get called when you have a standard IAP?

Comment: The documentation shows how to remove the observer, so I assumed it was necessary. To answer your question, I just tested a standard IAP, and the same thing happened: the transaction was successful, but `handlePurchase(_:)` was never called.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/setting_up_the_transaction_observer_for_the_payment_queue

Comment: I figured out the problem, @Paulw11, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. It was a stupid mistake on my part.

I'd been testing something, and had forgotten to remove a line in my `SceneDelegate`'s `sceneWillResignActive(_:)` in which I removed the observer. So, every time the payment sheet was presented, the observer was removed, which messed everything up.

```
func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    //Removing this line solved the problem
    //SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(SceneDelegate.inAppPurchases)
}
```